# How to add extra fields in ValueQuerySet (Django)?

Tags: json, django, serialization, markerclusterer

Basically, I want to convert the query_set to JSON. But I also want to add one more field something like `size = some number` in the query_set which is not present in the query_set attributes (it is computed attribute). Can you tell me how to do it?

```
    query_set = PotholeCluster.objects.all().values('bearing', 'center_lat', 'center_lon', 'grid_id')
    return JsonResponse(list(query_set), safe=False)
```

I tried the code below. It works, but I would like to know if there is any cleaner way to do this.

```
    query_set = PotholeCluster.objects.all()
    response_list = []
    for pc in query_set:
        d = {}
        d['bearing'] = pc.get_bearing()
        d['center_lat'] = pc.center_lat
        d['center_lon'] = pc.center_lat
        d['grid_id'] = pc.grid_id
        d['size'] = pc.pothole_set.all().count()
        response_list.append(d)
        serialized = json.dumps(response_list)
return HttpResponse(serialized, content_type='application/json')


class PotholeCluster(models.Model):
    center_lat = models.FloatField(default=0)
    center_lon = models.FloatField(default=0)
    snapped_lat = models.FloatField(default=0)
    snapped_lon = models.FloatField(default=0)
    size = models.IntegerField(default=-1)
    # avgspeed  in kmph
    speed = models.FloatField(default=-1)
    # in meters
    accuracy = models.FloatField(default=-1)
    # avg bearing in degree
    bearing = models.FloatField(default=-1)
    grid = models.ForeignKey(
        Grid,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )

    def __str__(self):
        raw_data = serialize('python', [self])
        output = json.dumps(raw_data[0]['fields'])
        return "pk = {}|{}".format(self.id, output)

    def get_bearing(self):
        if self.bearing != -1:
            return self.bearing
        potholes = self.pothole_set.all()
        bearings = [pothole.location.bearing for pothole in potholes]
        bearings.sort()
        i = 0
        if bearings[-1] >= 350:
            while bearings[-1] - bearings[i] >= 340:
                if bearings[i] <= 10:
                    bearings[i] += 360
                    i += 1
        self.bearing = sum(bearings) / len(bearings) % 360
        self.save()
        return self.bearing

    def get_size(self):
        if self.size != -1:
            return self.size
        self.size = len(self.pothole_set.all())
        self.save()
        return self.size
```

Comment: This is practically asking for debugging help, which you are unlikely to get here. You should learn the habit of developing your components independently. For example. Test your javascript by using a static piece of JSON. Then when that's working write your django view to produce the same json. When they are both working, plug them together.

Comment: @e4c5 After carefully reading every word, I found the bug! center_lat and center_lon were assigned same value and the markers were not in the view of google map. I am sorry. I removed the marker plotting code from the description. But I still want someone to answer my modified question. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: the current question cannot be answered by anyone because your model has not been shown. And there are calls like get_bearing which are black boxes

Comment: @e4c5 I have added the code for the model. Thanks for mentioning it.